# How do you access Airflow Web Interface?

Tags: airflow

Hi I am taking a datacamp class on how to use Airflow and it shows how to create dags once you have access to an Airflow Web Interface.

Is there an easy way to create an account in the Airflow Web Interface? I am very lost on how to do this or is this just an enterprise tool where they provide you access to it once you pay?

Answer (score 2):

You must do this on terminal. Run these commands:

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.2.5

PYTHON_VERSION="$(python --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"

CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt"

pip install "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}"

airflow standalone
```

Then, in there, you can see the username and password provided.

Then, open Chrome and search for:

```
localhost:8080
```

And write the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

airflow has a web interface as well by default and default user pass is : airflow/airflow
you can run it by using :

```
airflow webserver --port 8080
```

then open the link : http://localhost:8080

if you want to make a new username by this command:

```
airflow create_user [-h] [-r ROLE] [-u USERNAME] [-e EMAIL] [-f FIRSTNAME]
                    [-l LASTNAME] [-p PASSWORD] [--use_random_password]
```

learn more about [Running Airflow locally](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html)

Comment: thanks @eshirvana I'll try this out. So will this only work if I have my computer on everytime I want to start a DAG on a scheduler or do I need to have this in Databricks so that it is outside my local machine?

Comment: @nak5120 then you have to enable it on cloud , most cloud services support airflow like google cloud.[google cloud airflow](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-web-interface)

Comment: interesting, thanks. I will do more research into this. So to confirm, is it not possible to run airflow command line in Databricks so that it's not local? Only google cloud airflow?

Comment: @nak5120 databricks is just a datawarehouse/data lake on cloud , you can connect to databricks from your local machine , from another cloud server , from anywhere. so you can install airflow anywhere  ( your local machine , another cloud server , etc) to connect to databricks

Answer (score 1):

You should install it , it is a python package not a website to register on.

The easiest way to install  Airflow is:

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

if you need extra packages with it:

```
pip install apache-airflow[postgres,gcp]
```

finally run the webserver and the scheduler in different cmd :

```
airflow webserver # it is by default 8080

airflow scheduler
```

Comment: thanks @iyed-saddly, is this only possible via local machine? My end goal from this is to have this running in the cloud in databricks

Comment: I have no idea how to run it there but you can run it in Google Cloud Platform through cloud composer

Answer (score 1):

Install airflow by pulling the Git repository

```
pip install 'apache-airflow==2.6.1' \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.1/constraints-3.7.txt"
```

Run the application in standalone with.

```
airflow standalone
```

*NB: Airflow Standalone is for development purposes only. Do not use this in production!*

Make sure to collect your **usnm and pw**,
[image]

Finally, run your localhost from your browser and input your credential

```
localhost:8080
```

You can now access your DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) web interface to build and schedule jobs.

Refer to https://github.com/apache/airflow for more information.